# Creating a JPA (Hibernate) proxy and set the Primary key later

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, proxy

Well, I'm working on a library where I need to create a JPA reference of some serialized entity objects.

The time I need to create the entity reference I don't have the ID field value so I somehow first need to create the proxy and then set the id. So I cannot use the

```
entitymanager.getReference
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: That's not possible with JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Without an id an entity is in "detached" state, which means it's not governed by hibernate. You need to fetch it from db (or get reference), persist or make managed in other way, so it's not possible.

Comment: That's what I was thinking of myself, Just wanted to double check in SO. Thank you